# How remove SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW android permission in react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

How remove SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW android permission in React Native?

I remove it from `AndroidManifest.xml` but it don't removed from app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

to manifest tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.bepaw.esportninja">
```

and add

```
tools:node="remove"
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW " tools:node="remove" />
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission from AndroidManifest.xml file
2. Create additional AndroidManifest.xml file in 'src/debug' directory
3. Make it look like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
</manifest>
```

After that your APK will have SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission only for 'build' variant but not for 'release'.